# Is bcrypt viable for large web sites?

Tags: security, performance, authentication, passwords, scalability

I've been on the bcrypt bandwagon for a while now, but I'm having trouble answering a simple nagging question.

Imagine I have a reasonably successful web site in the U.S... about 100,000 active users that each have activity patterns requiring 2 to 3 authentication attempts on average over the course of a typical American business day (12 hours when you include timezones). That's 250,000 authentication requests per day, or about 5.8 authentications per second.

One of the neat things about bcrypt is that you tune it, so that over time it scales as hardware does, to stay ahead of the crackers. A common tuning is to get it to take just over 1/10 of a second per hash creation... let's say I get it to .173 seconds per hash. I chose that number because it just so happens that .173 seconds per hash works out to about 5.8 hashes per second. In other words, my hypothetical web server is literally spending all it's time doing nothing but authenticating users. Never mind actually doing any useful work.

To address this issue, I would have to either tune bcrypt way down (not a good idea) or get a dedicated server just to do authentications, and nothing else. Now imagine that the site grows and adds another 100,000 users. Suddenly I need two servers: again, doing nothing but authentication. Don't even start thinking about load spikes, as you have light and busy periods throughout a day.

As I see it right now, this is one of those problems that would be nice to have, and bcrypt would still be worth the trouble. But I'd like to know if I'm I missing something obvious here? Something subtle? Or can anyone out there actually point to a well known web site running a whole server farm just for the authentication portion of their site?

Comment: It's viable if you have the money. Some sites don't consider full-HTTPS viable because of the few percentage increase in bandwidth and processing power required. But other large sites have no problem enforcing an HTTPS only policy. It just depends on your budget and priorities.

Comment: That's not a server dedicated to auth: it's a core.

Comment: @Peter - it's more than just a core. Otherwise black hats could just throw more parallel hardware at the problem a la graphics cards.

Comment: They can. Until they have more cores than the size of the key space, splitting the key space is the obvious way to speed up a search.

Comment: @PeterTaylor is right. bcrypt is designed so that the computation of one crypt operation can not be parallelized (by heavy data dependence). Your webserver only has to perform multiple diffrent crypts, which can be distributed to the many cheap cpu cores.

Answer (score 5):

Even if you tune bcrypt to take only, say, 1/1000 of a second, that's still quite a bit slower than simple hashing — a quick and dirty Perl benchmark says my not-so-new computer can calculate about 300,000 SHA-256 hashes per second.

Yes, the difference between 1000 and 300,000 is only about 8 bits, but that's still 8 bits of security margin you wouldn't have otherwise, and that difference is only going to increase as CPUs get faster.

Also, if you use [scrypt](http://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt.html) instead of bcrypt, it will retain its memory-hardness property even if the iteration count is lowered, which will still make brute forcing it harder to parallelize.

Comment: Yes, even a 1/10000 second would be better, the goal is to prevent calculating millions of values per second. And of course you can start with a short time and adjust this value later on, when you are able to estimate the impact.